# how can i measure distance of an detected object from camera in video using opencv?

Tags: opencv

All i know is that the height and width of an object in video. can someone guide me to calculate distance of an detected object from camera in video using c or c++? is there any algorithm or formula to do that?
thanks in advance

Comment: you have to calibrate your camera - put object in distance 50cm from camera and check how many pixels of picture does your object measure - than its lineary changing

Comment: Hey @martin-ch , it's definitely **not** a linear change. The physics involved work with some trigonometric functions, so it's more complex than multiplying with a factor

Comment: martin thanks, let me explain what i understand e.g a square box is placed 50cm away from camera and in image box width and height is  (10 x 10) i.e total pixels are 100. that means 1pixel=0.5cm and distance from camera is 50cm. is this is the only way to calculate  distance?

Answer (score 1):

Martin Ch was correct in saying that you need to calibrate your camera, but as vasile pointed out, it is not a linear change.  Calibrating your camera means finding this matrix

```
camera_matrix = [fx,0 ,cx,
                 0,fy,cy,
                 0,0, 1];
```

This matrix operates on a 3 dimensional coordinate (x,y,z) and converts it into a 2 dimensional [homogeneous](http://www.songho.ca/math/homogeneous/homogeneous.html) coordinate.  To convert to your regular euclidean (x,y) coordinate just divide the first and second component by the third.  So now what are those variables doing?

**cx/cy:** They exist to let you change coordinate systems if you like.  For instance you might want the origin in camera space to be in the top left of the image and the origin in world space to be in the center.  In that case

```
cx = -width/2;
cy = -height/2;
```

If you are not changing coordinate systems just leave these as 0.

**fx/fy:**  These specify your focal length in units of x pixels and y pixels, these are very often close to the same value so you may be able to just give them the same value f.  These parameters essentially define how strong perspective effects are.  The mapping from a world coordinate to a screen coordinate (as you can work out for yourself from the above matrix) assuming no cx and cy is

```
xsc = fx*xworld/zworld;
ysc = fy*yworld/zworld;
```

As you can see the important quantity that makes things bigger closer up and smaller farther away is the **ratio** f/z.  It is not linear, but by using homogenous coordinates we can still use linear transforms.

In short.  With a calibrated camera, and a known object size in world coordinates you can calculate its distance from the camera.  If you are missing either one of those it is impossible.  Without knowing the object size in world coordinates the best you can do is map its screen position to a ray in world coordinates by determining the ration xworld/zworld (knowing fx).

Comment: Hammer thanks for your detailed reply. but in my project as i mentioned in my question i have to detect different objects and i do not know about their actual size's.All i know is width and height of object in pixels i.e object is enclosed in a rectangle. so what should i do in this situation? is there any solution?

Comment: @yas the best you can do is map the object to a ray in world space.  If you don't know its original size but you do know f you can determine xworld/zworld, which essentially gives you a slope.

Comment: @yas if you really need to know the actual z position and its ray in world space is not enough, start trying to think of other pieces of knowledge you have that could be put together.  Is the scene all at the same depth value?  Is the scene moving at a known velocity?  Can you take two pictures of the same scene from two different positions (where the two projected rays intersect would give you an actual z coordinate).  Often there is some way to get the information you need

Comment: i thought Inverse Perspective Mapping would work for me. Using IPM, we can transform the forward facing image to a top-down "bird's eye" view, in which there is a linear relationship between distances in the image and in the real world. is it work in my case?

Comment: @yas No, that will not work.  Inverse Perspective mapping gains you no new information, all it does is present the information you already have without the effect of perspective.  You will still only be able to determine the ratio xworld/zworld.  Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11803294/how-to-calculate-distance-from-succesive-images/11803578#11803578) explanation make it any more clear?

Answer (score 0):

i don´t think it is easy if have to use camera only,

consider about to use 3rd device/sensor like kinect/stereo camera,

then you will get the depth(z) from the data.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenNI