# How to calculate Distance from succesive images

Tags: image-processing, distance

Suppose I take an image at one location and after shifting the camera by a fixed distance I take another picture.Is there any way to determine the distance shifted using these two images.?

Comment: camera calibration search kor. not exactly identical to what you're looking for, however should help in the related concepts/math. codevita?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not without knowing something about the scene you are looking at.  Picture some object.  Now move the object twice as far away from you and double its size. It will look identical to you.  If you now move to the left the object will move to the right but how far it appears to move will depend on how far you moved it away from you.  This effect is called parallax and is what lets you determine the relative depth of objects if you know exactly how far you moved.  Unfortunately it also means that without knowing the depth of what you are looking at you can't know how far you moved.

If you can define the location of some points in world space then it becomes possible.