# How to find angle b/w camera and pixel in a image?

Tags: opencv

I want to know angle between camera and point in the image. is it possible to calculate? if yes then can i relate this angle with angle of triangle.
thanks

Comment: A camera represents a point.  Asking what the angle between two points is has no meaning.  You need to define two lines and ask what the angle between them is.  To define two lines you need three points.  What is your third point?

Comment: I want to calculate angle with respect to ground.so second line is perpendicular from camera to the ground.

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in response to your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11790410/how-can-i-measure-distance-of-an-detected-object-from-camera-in-video-using-open) if your camera is calibrated, you can define the slope of a ray in world space corresponding to any point in the image.  You can find the angle between that ray and the [image plane](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_plane) which does not necessarily correspond to any plane in world space.  You want to know the angle between that ray and an unknown plane however which cannot be done without depth information.  Consider this ambiguity.

```
1
|\
| \
|  \
|   \
-----
2
|\
| \
|  \
|   \
\    \
  \   \
    \  \
      \ \
        \\
```

The rays extending from the camera in 1 and 2 are identical.  In 2 however one ray extends farther than the other meaning the bottom left and right angles change dramatically.